# Characterization of algebraic integers providing a prime ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domains

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer and let $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ be the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

**Question**: How to characterize an algebraic integer $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$?

*Example*: if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} = \mathbb{Z}$, so that $\alpha \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ is a prime ideal iff $\alpha$ is a prime number (up to a sign).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a necessary condition is that the norm of $\alpha$ must be a prime power, as if $\alpha\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ is a prime ideal, then $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}/\alpha\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ is a finite field with cardinality $|N_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$. This condition is clearly not sufficient, as taking a prime power in $\mathbb{Z}$ shows.

Comment: @AlexWertheim: If I am not mistaken, $α$ is a unit in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ when (by definition) its norm is one.

Comment: Trivially, $\alpha=0$ qualifies. As remarked, for $\alpha\ne0$ we must have $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)|=p^m$ with $p$ prime and $1\leq m\leq n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. If $m=1$ then $\alpha\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is a prime ideal. If $m=n$, the ideal is prime iff $p$ is inert in $K$; in that case, $\alpha$ simply equals $p\beta$ for some unit $\beta\in\mathcal{O}_{K}$. Don't know whether much can be said in case $1<m<n$.

Comment: If $m=n-1$, for $\alpha\mathcal{O}_{K}$ to be prime one would have $p\in\alpha\mathcal{O}_{K}$, hence $\beta=\alpha/p$ is integral (which can be verified easily enough) of norm $p$, hence $\beta\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is prime, and $p\mathcal{O}_{K}$ $=$ $\alpha\mathcal{O}_{K}\cdot\beta\mathcal{O}_{K}$, So $p$ would need to split as the product of a degree $n-1$ and a degree $1$ prime in $K$. But this is not a criterion that can be readily checked from the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ alone - even if it factorizes as $x^{n-1}(x-a)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$.

Comment: $\beta=p/\alpha$, of course.

Comment: If $x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}x+a_0$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $|a_{0}|=p^{m}$, where $m\le n$, for $\beta=p/\alpha$ to be an integer, a condition necessary for $\alpha\mathcal{O}_{K}$ to be prime, one needs $a_{i}\equiv0$ mod $p^{m-i}$ for $0<i<m$.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee: you should replace all your comments by one answer (that you could improve at your convenience).